# what kind of telescope eyepieces is best for viewing planets up close

Tags: telescope-lens

ok so I am a total amateur when it comes to telescopes and lens, and this is probably a pretty stupid question, but I am trying to find a lens/eyepiece that is good for viewing Jupiter and Saturn up close, and I have no idea what I am looking for, I have an Orion Sky Quest XT8 plus reflector telescope, (not sure if that matters) but if someone knows what I am looking for pls lmk, thx Noelle:)

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8788/616

Answer (score 2):

To get good views of Jupiter and Saturn you need quite high magnification - probably 100 times or more. The XT8 has a focal length of 1200 mm and so to get that magnification will need an eyepiece of 12 mm focal length. I believe the scope comes with a 10mm eyepiece which will give 120 times magnification, which should give decent views.

You could go for higher magnification with shorter focal length eyepieces, but if you do you will find that the object you are observing scoots across the field of view rather quickly and you will spend more time moving the telescope than actually observing.  As you get more experienced you may find you get more adept at moving the scope, and so could use more magnification.

It’s important that the mirrors of the scope are properly aligned (collimated) so as to get the sharpest views. The manual should tell you how to do that.